# Allowing multiple passwords attached to one account (Linux)

Tags: linux, passwords, user-accounts

Is it possible to have more than one password simultaneously attached to a login account in Linux?

I'd like to be able to add a temporarily-authorized user to an account on my web server, but don't want to have to change the login afterwards.

Is this possible?

Even cooler would be if this could be done with a timer of some kind so the temporary password would auto-die after, say, 24 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PAM can do [all sorts](http://web.archive.org/web/20110612173211/http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/modules.html) of awesome auth stuff. That list is probably a bit out of date, so have a look around.

Comment: It is not: PAM updates very rarely, and why authentication framework must be updated often?

Comment: The modules, not the framework...

Comment: I'm looking with a new issue from AskUbuntu (server) but the link is dead with a 404 :-(

Comment: I suggest changing the link to http://web.archive.org/web/20110612173211/http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/modules.html

Comment: So, how does it answer the question?

Answer (score 4):

[OPIE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPIE_Authentication_System) is probably something you would like for your needs.  Also, remember that permissions are set based on the User ID, not the login name.  So, you can share the same UID of someone else without sharing the same password, login name, home directory and login shell (as well as any other place that let you configure your system without the login shell).  PAM as also a very flexible (but complex) system that you can configure to do a lot of weird stuff (like allowing login only from some place at some time, or dual-factor authentication).

Comment: the duplicated uid is not a direction I'd considered yet - thanks :)